# Highcharts heatmap scale one decimal place

Tags: highcharts, grid, scale, heatmap, decimal-point

I am using Highcharts heatmap and would like to display one decimal place on the scale range. See image below. I would like to show 0.0, -5.0, -10.0, -15.0, -20.0.
[image: HeatMap]

I have increased the range of scale by adding "symbolHeight" to legend. See below code:

```
legend: {
  align: 'right',
  layout: 'vertical',
  margin: 0,
  verticalAlign: 'top',
  y: 42,
  symbolHeight: 360
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to display the decimal points by adding

```
labels: {
  format: '{value:.1f}'
}
```

to colorAxis. See edited fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/er1187/u7oax1ue/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can format the Y-Axis decimals with using **[yAxis.labels.format](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.format)**.

For 0.0, -5.0, -10.0, -15.0, -20.0 ticks, you need to use **[minTickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.minTickInterval)**

Just add this code;

```
yAxis: {
          labels: {
            format: '{value:.1f}'
          },
          minTickInterval: 5
       }
```

Example: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25t61860/3/)**

Comment: Please see jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/er1187/u7oax1ue/ I have yAxis labels already. I am trying to fix the coloraxis scale

Comment: Sorry, there were no example jsFiddle in your question but I see that you solved the problem based on my answer.